# Is it possible to hide the nodes/slaves in jenkins view?

Tags: jenkins

we are using Jenkins LTS 2.150.1, Is it possible to hide the nodes/slaves list (by default at the lower left side of the screen) from "regular" users (i.e - not admins).

Is it even possible?
Am I missing something?

I tried:

1. looking in the configuration of the server, couldn't find any "switch" or anything of that sort to hide it.
2. looking for a plugin to do that, but couldn't find anything that isn't changing the entire "look and feel" of the basic jenkins theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be that this feature is not added yet. See [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16502) ticket.